# How do I display sweetalert2 radio options vertically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert2

I am working with sweetalert2 to create a popup list of radio options. My list of options are more than 3 and most are longer than 5 words. So, the display output is not nice since it is displayed horizontally, as you can see in the screenshot below.

What can I do so that the radio button will be displayed vertically?

Current output:
[image]

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try add the css:

```
.swal2-radio {
    display: grid !important;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. Just another quick question, is there any way to make the font normal (not bold)? I'm not sure if it's because of some other css interfering.

Comment: Welcome. I think some css might override the default since the sample on sweetalert2 does not bold. You can change that by overriding the `.swal2-radio > input` to set the `font-weight` to `normal`

Comment: Is this the right way to do it? `.swal2-radio input{ font-weight: normal; }` because it's not working

Comment: You can try `.swal2-radio > input { font-weight: normal !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
.swal2-radio label{
  display: block
}

.swal2-modal .swal2-radio label {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/ayx0fkz3/16/